# Public folders or "All Users" folder in Mac?

Tags: macos, permission, user-account, ftp

I have a web server in OS X Server with an open source digital asset management system installed: [ResourceSpace](http://www.resourcespace.org/).

The main Web Root folder is shared via FTP and with permissions set to "All Users". I'd like to determine if "all Users" refers specifically to all the users in the OS X Server or if it is actually "Public" and it means anyone can access it (more like an "Everyone" permission in Windows).

Comment: Important to note that by removing the "All Users" share ResourceSpace will not work. (access forbidden right from the login page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With permissions set to "All Users", any local or directory-based user can access the item when authenticated. It refers specifically to all the users in OS X Server. **The folder is not public, but accessible to all authenticated local or directory users on your server**